# My code is not running (flutter) in this part (uri)

Tags: flutter, android-studio, flutter-appbar

This is my code and this part, code is not running
I don't know what I do please help me. Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`http` requires an `Uri` not an `String`

This is the signature of the method

```dart
Future<Response> get(Uri url, {Map<String, String>? headers})
```

So you should use

```dart
http.get(Uri.parse(url)).then //Your code
```